# How to use sed to convert Text file to CSV file using python

Tags: python, sed

I've been trying to convert this format:

```
2012-03-16 13:47:30.465 -0400   START  Running    Lab.script    19    on_the
```

The only way I could figure it out was using sed, however when I try to use subprocess in python, it won't read the proper command and it will give me an error. Also, it's not the right format, I'd like it to be similar to csv.

This is what I'm working with currently:

```
   f = open("newlogfile.csv", "w")
   p = subprocess.Popen(["sed","-e","'s/^[ ]*//g'","-e","'s/\([0-9a-zA-Z\.]*\)","*/\1;/g'","LogFile.txt"], stdout=f, stderr=f)

   f.close()
```

I'm pretty new to using subprocess and very new to using sed, any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

UPDATE:

```
  fin = csv.reader(open('LogFile.txt', 'rb'),delimiter='\t')
  fout = csv.writer(open('newLogFile.csv', 'w'))

  for row in fin:
    fout.writerow(';'.join(row))
```

Comment: could we see the error message?

Comment: what is the format you are trying to convert to. You could just replace all the \s and \t with , and get a csv. Is that what you are looking for. Why would you use sed

Comment: how many files? how big is it / are they? BTW: it already is in CSV format (if you can use tabs as separators and there are tabs in your source file instead of spaces)...

Comment: doesn't python have a csv processor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really look into the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module for a cleaner method of making this conversion, I believe you will want code that looks something like this:

```
fin = csv.reader(open('LogFile.txt', 'rb'), delimiter='\t')
fout = open('newLogFile.csv', 'w')
for row in fin:
    fout.write(';'.join(row) + '\n')
```

The rest of this answer should help to explain why your sed method isn't working and how to fix it.

Try changing your command list to the following:

```
["sed", "-e", "s/^[ ]*//g", "-e", "s/\([0-9a-zA-Z\.]*\)*/\1;/g", "LogFile.txt"]
```

Note that the second `s/.../.../g` was split into two entries in your original example, which is likely what was causing the problem.  Also you do not need the single quotes because `Popen` will do whatever escaping is necessary to pass the entire entry in the argument list to `sed` as a single argument.

You should also replace `stderr=f` with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, which is the correct way to send stderr to the same place as stdout.

Complete code:

```
f = open("newlogfile.csv", "w")
args = ["sed", "-e", "s/^[ ]*//g", "-e", "s/\([0-9a-zA-Z\.]*\)*/\1;/g", "LogFile.txt"]
p = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
f.close()
```

Comment: I tried to use csv.writer() however, when I used it, it seprated every single letter and number with a comma, and I just want it separated based on the same format thats in the original text file.

Comment: @user1186173 - I haven't used the csv module much, but I think what you would want to do here is use `csv.reader(open('Logfile.txt', delimiter='\t'))` to create a reader, and then for each row in that reader write `'; '.join(row)` to the .csv file that you open for writing (normal `open()` call, not with `csv.writer()`).

Comment: Ok, I did what you suggested, I updated this page with the new code. 
The csv file looks a lot better than it did, although, it looks like this now. 2,0,1,2,-,0,3,-,1,6, ,1,3,:,4,7,:,3,0,.,4,6,5, ,-,0,4,0,0,;,S,T,A,R,T,;

Comment: @user1186173 - See my recent edit, it has some csv code at the top that I think may do what you want.

Comment: Thats exactly it!! Thank you very much for your help!